# How to send a message in android 2.2?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send a message (sms/mms) with android 2.2. First I made an intent chooser with an ACTION_SEND to select which to use  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Resources.getString("InvitationSubject", getBaseContext()));
String body = Resources.getString("InvitationBody", getBaseContext()) + Local.User.FirstName;
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Invite friends"));
```

But in that case, the selector show 'Bluetooth, Messaging, Google+, Gmail'. I want to show ONLY Messaging or other messaging apps.

I saw in the sdk docs there's a new CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING to use but it's only available in the API level 15. I have to keep API level 8. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
String body = Resources.getString("InvitationBody", getBaseContext()) + Local.User.FirstName;
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Don't forget to add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />` in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type mms-sms, like so

```
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to send message

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "message subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Pick a Share method"));
```

Gives following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: SEND_SMS permission is not required.